# 100vh doesnt cover the whole screen on screen size less then 326px

Tags: css, css-position, fixed, viewport-units

I am using `min-height: 100vh;` property and it works good on all screen size. My footer is always at the bottom.

[image]

There is a problem when I go to Chrome dev tools and test the site responsivnes.
If I go below 326px my footer starts to go up and this is because 100vh container is not covering the whole page anymore. I tried adding `height 100%` to html and body and few other tricks but it doesnt help. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: share the code ..

Comment: Sorry, cant do that. It's a big project with styles in css modules in different components. 
But in the essence fotter has position fixed to the bottom and the first element inside the body that wraps everthing has min-height: 100vh;

Comment: so how can we help you then? :) ... inside your *big project* there is something creating the issue

Comment: Please add a [mcve], otherwise it's a waste of time.

Comment: Does it work if you wait a few seconds so that Chrome dev tools can recalculate everything? When I tested, it seems to be glitching on stackoverflow too but gets OK after a few seconds.

Comment: I guess its a zooming issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I figured out what was the problem. It was a third party library Semantic-UI-React that had ```min-width: 326px``` property on <body> element.

Answer (score 0):

@Igor-Vuk, Please try with below code snippet

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .full-height{
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

Thanks!